# Stored procedure and trigger execution blocking

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, clr, database-trigger, sqlclr

I have SQL Server 2017 Express database that is accessed by up to 6 tablets that connect via an Angular 7 app using REST web services.

I have a stored procedure that allows a new user to be inserted into a specific database table. The insert will always only insert 1 record at a time, but with 6 clients, the stored procedure could be called by each client almost simultaneously.

The last step of the process is to print an agreement form to a specific printer.  Initially this was going to be handled on the client side, but the tablets do not have the ability to print to a network printer, so that functionality now needs to reside on the server side.

With this new requirement, the agreement form is an RTF document that is being read, placeholder values replaced with values from the insert statement, written to a temporary file and then printed to the network printer via the application (Wordpad most likely) that is associated with the RTF file format.

There is also an MS Access front-end app that uses linked servers to connect to the database, but doesn't have the ability to create new users, but will need to be able to initiate the "print agreement" operation in the case of an agreement not being printed due to printer issue, network issue, etc.

I have the C# code written to perform the action of reading/modifying/writing/printing of the form that uses the UseShellExecute StartInfo property with the Process.Start method.

Since the file read/modify/write/print process takes a few seconds, I am concerned about having the stored procedure for adding the registration blocking for that length of time.

I am pretty sure that I am going to need a CLR stored procedure so that the MS Access front-end can initiate the print operation, so what I have come up with is either the "Add_Registration" stored procedure (Transact-SQL) will call the CLR stored procedure to do the read/modify/write/print operation, or an insert trigger (either CLR or Transact-SQL) on the table that calls the CLR stored procedure to read/modify/write/print.

I could avoid the call from the trigger to the stored procedure by duplicating the code in both the CLR trigger and the CLR stored procedure if there is a compelling reason to do so, but was trying to avoid having duplicate code if possible.

The solutions that I am currently considering are as follows, but am unsure of how SQL Server handles various scenarios:

1. A CLR or Transact-SQL `Insert` trigger on the registration table that calls a CLR stored procedure that does the reading/modifying/writing/printing process.
2. A CLR stored procedure that does the reading/modifying/writing/printing process, being called from the current `add_registration` Transact-SQL stored procedure

The questions I keep coming back to are:

1. How are `Insert` CLR triggers executed if multiple inserts are done at the same or nearly the same time (only 1 per operation), are they queued up an then processed synchronously or are they executed immediately?
2. Same question as #1 except with a Transact-SQL trigger
3. How are CLR stored procedures handled if they are called by multiple clients at the same or nearly the same time, are they queued up an then processed synchronously, or is each call to the stored procedure executed immediately?
4. Same question as #3 except with a Transact-SQL stored procedure
5. If a CLR stored procedure is called from a Transact-SQL trigger, is the trigger blocked until the stored procedure returns or is the call to the stored procedure spawned out to it's own process (or similar method) with the trigger returning immediately?
6. Same question as #5 except with a CLR trigger calling the CLR stored procedure

I am looking for any other suggestions and/or clarifications on how SQL Server handles these scenarios.

Comment: This sounds more like a report than a bunch of CLR to me. Have you considered an SSRS report for this? It would be a million times simpler than procedures and triggers with CLR.

Comment: I should have been more clear about the agreements.  I looked at Reporting services, but there was a need for very inexperienced users to modify the agreement with the tools they have and know so it was decided by the customer that they could do it "best" using Word (I at least got them to agree to RTF format since it was easier to edit).

Comment: You do know that SSRS can export directly to Word right? There is a little disc icon on the right side of the toolbar at the top of every report. You can open the report in the current viewer or Excel, pdf or Word. Can't get much simpler for inexperienced users. :D

Comment: @SeanLange it isn't exporting to Word that is the issue, the output file is not saved after it is printed.  The issue is with them being able to modify the document template with the tools they have and know and not having to learn something new in order to modify the document template.  What little bit I read regarding Reporting Services indicated that you had to use the Report Builder, or Report Designer that was installed with SSDT.

Comment: Yes to develop the report you have to use a report designer. But the end user doesn't even know that tool exists. They simply click something in your application which opens a web page at a specific url (with query string values to provide some info to the report). The user just sees a report in a web browser. They do not have the ability to modify the template of the report. But it sounds like in your case they don't anyway so that isn't a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

There is no queuing unless you implement it yourself, and there are a few ways to do that. So for multiple concurrent sessions, they are all acting independently. Of course, when it comes to writing to the DB (`INSERT` / `UPDATE` / `DELETE` / etc) then they clearly operate in the order in which they submit their requests.

I'm not sure why you are including the trigger in any of this, but as it relates to concurrency, triggers execute within a system-generated transaction initiated by the DML statement that fired the trigger. This doesn't mean that you will have single-threaded INSERTs, but if the trigger is calling a SQLCLR stored procedure that takes a second or two to complete (and the trigger cannot continue until the stored procedure completes / exits) then there are locks being held on the table for the duration of that operation. Those locks might not prevent other sessions from inserting at the same time, but you might have other operations attempting to modify that table that require a conflicting lock that will need to wait until the insert + trigger + SQLCLR proc operation completes. Of course, that might only be a problem if you have frequent inserts, but that depends on how often you expect new users, and that might not be frequent enough to worry about.

---

I'm also not sure why you need to print anything in that moment. It might be much simpler on a few levels if you simply have a flag / `BIT` column indicating whether or not the agreement has been printed, defaulted to `0`. Then, you can have an external console app, scheduled via SQL Server Agent or Windows Scheduled Tasks, executed once every few minutes, that reads from the `Users` table `WHERE HasPrintedAgreement = 0`. Each row has the necessary fields for the replacement values, it prints each one, and upon printing, it updates that `UserID` setting `HasPrintedAgreement = 1`. You can even schedule this console app to execute once every minute if you always want the agreements immediately.

Comment: The reason for the immediate print is that they have to physically sign the document and have the data verified before the registration can be moved into the active table.  The registrations happen in kind of a "group" mode where 3-4 people come in and register at the same time and then you can go for an hour or more before the next group that comes in needs to register.  They only have to register the 1st time that they visit the facility.

Comment: The "IsPrinted" is one of the other solutions I am looking at (either windows service or an "autorun" app, but thought that having it in the db would keep things more centralized and with fewer moving parts.  If the original app had not been done in Access (the initial app was just someone's attempt to keep track of the paper agreements - then they were given tablets so of course they needed to automate the registration process), I would have spawned a thread in the app that would periodically check for new records.

Comment: @EricB As I said, you can schedule it in SQL Server Agent. That keeps it more centralized within SQL Server yet not in-process. You can even schedule it to run every second if need be, and in that case it will not run more than one process at a time. Wouldn't that effectively be the same thing as having a service check with that same frequency? I don't see that being noticeably slower than "real-time" printing via trigger, yet it's a more reliable solution that also reduces contention as compared to going with a trigger that doesn't complete nearly instantly.

Comment: I somehow read right over the "SQL Server Agent" and only saw "Windows Scheduled Tasks".  I am going to look into the SQL Server Agent 1st thing in the morning.  Thanks for that idea.